# Page Reloads On Fetching API

Tags: json, typescript, api, async-await, github-api

I'm currently working on Github user API, and I want test how things works before moving on project but, I go one issue

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button') as HTMLButtonElement
const input = document.querySelector('input') as HTMLInputElement

const  USER_API: string = 'https://api.github.com/users/callmenikk'

const fetchData = async () => {
    const fetchUser = await fetch(USER_API)
    const userData = fetchUser.json()
    userData.then(resolve => console.log(resolve))
}

btn.addEventListener('click', fetchData)
```

with this function I want to output my personal user data in console but, it reloads page and puts question mark in ending of link like that `http://localhost:3000/?` without outputing my JSON in console, but without EventListner to put this function outside, it works well. what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guest type of your `btn` (html attribute `type`) is `submit`, then when you click the button, a form will be submitted. That action reloads your page.

To fix that issue, you can remove the button type, or ignore submit event in the event handler function.

```
const fetchData = async (event) => { // event parameter
    event.preventDefault(); // ignore event
    const fetchUser = await fetch(USER_API)
    const userData = fetchUser.json()
    userData.then(resolve => console.log(resolve))
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding but I've already fixed that, problem was, about form must had `onSubmit="return false;` and my input filed had no type `text`, that was my issue, I tried that one too and worked